# Remove duplicates from list based on duplicate index in another list

Tags: java, list, hashset

I have 2 Lists: `Names` & `IDs`.

There are cases where the same name will appear multiple times. For example:

```
Names = {'ben','david','jerry','tom','ben'}
IDs   = {'123','23456','34567','123','123'}
```

I know I can use

```
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<>( Names );
Names .clear();
Names .addAll( set );
```

In order to remove duplicates, however, it not what I want.

What I would like to do is to check where `Names` has a duplicate value which in this case will be the last value and then remove from `IDs` the value at that position so the final result will be:

```
Names = {'ben','david','jerry','tom'}
IDs   = {'123','23456','34567','123'}
```

How can I get the index of the duplicated value in order to remove it from the second list? or is there some easy and fast way to do it?

I'm sure I can solve it by using a loop but I try to avoid it.

**SOLUTION:**

I changed the code to use:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

When using:

```
map.put(name,id);
```

It might not do the job since there are cases where the same name has different it and it won't allow duplicate in the name so just changed to `map.put(id,name)` and it did the job.

Thank you

Comment: why don't you use a single set of a class that holds an ID and a name? it seems you are using them together

Comment: If there are different IDs for a duplicate name, which ID should be kept in the result?

Comment: @AlexRudenko I want to remove values where both Name and ID are same. If Name is same but ID is different I would like to keep it.

Comment: how about a mutlimap? you could hold all of them with a multimap then figure out which ones you want to remove. also, what about same ID but different names?

Comment: Ben, in your final result you keep a pair `Ben`/`123` - you just removed its duplicate

Answer (score 3):

You could collect the data from both input arrays/lists into a set of pairs and then recollect the pairs back to two new lists (or clear and reuse existing `names`/`IDs` lists):

```java
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("ben","david","jerry","tom","ben");
List<String> IDs   = Arrays.asList("123","23456","34567","123","123");

// assuming that both lists have the same size
// using list to store a pair
Set<List<String>> deduped = IntStream.range(0, names.size())
                 .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.asList(names.get(i), IDs.get(i)))
                 .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));

System.out.println(deduped);
System.out.println("-------");

List<String> dedupedNames = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> dedupedIDs = new ArrayList<>();
deduped.forEach(pair -> {dedupedNames.add(pair.get(0)); dedupedIDs.add(pair.get(1)); });

System.out.println(dedupedNames);
System.out.println(dedupedIDs);
```

Output:

```
[[ben, 123], [david, 23456], [jerry, 34567], [tom, 123]]
-------
[ben, david, jerry, tom]
[123, 23456, 34567, 123]
```

Comment: This is nice, maybe I would have collected pairs to a set of entries (instead of a set of lists), but that's a minor detail

Comment: @Alex Rudenko thanks for the answer. I couldn't use it since it required min API 24 but I'm sure it is a great answer.

Comment: You need it for Android?

Answer (score 1):

You can collect as a map using `Collectors.toMap` then get the keySet and values from map for names and ids list.

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("ben","david","jerry","tom","ben");
List<String> ids   = Arrays.asList("123","23456","34567","123","123");
Map<String, String> map = 
          IntStream.range(0, ids.size())
                   .boxed()
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> names.get(i), i -> ids.get(i),
                                             (a,b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
List<String> newNames = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
List<String> newIds = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

You can do map creation part using loop also

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
  if(!map.containsKey(names.get(i))) {
    map.put(names.get(i), ids.get(i));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add your names one by one to a set as long as `Set.add` returns true and if it returns false store the index of that element in a list (indices to remove). Then sort the indices list in reverse order and use `List.remove(int n)` on both your names list and id list:

```
List<String> names = ...
List<String> ids = ...
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
List<Integer> toRemove = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i< names.size(); i ++){
    if(!set.add(names.get(i))){
        toRemove.add(i);
    }
}

Collections.sort(toRemove, Collections.reverseOrder());
for (int i : toRemove){
    names.remove(i);  
    ids.remove(i);
}

System.out.println(toRemove);

System.out.println(names);
System.out.println(ids);
```

Comment: Great answer, just a minor comment: `toRemove` may be a sorted set with reverse ordering.